# When does UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault not result in autocorrection being enabled?

Tags: ios, autocorrect

The developer docs for [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/autocorrectionType) state:

> The default value for this property is UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault, which for most input methods results in auto-correction being enabled

Is there any documentation on what input methods or situations would result in auto-correction being disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there's such documentation (I couldn't find any), but one possible example of auto-correction being disabled is when a `UITextField` instance (which conforms to `UITextInputTraits` by default) is used for secure entering:

```
textfield.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

In other words, the system doesn't auto-correct the password you type as expected.

If you still need an information about specific cases when auto-correction is disabled, you may try asking this question on [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/).